# Python в C++ коде

Tags: c++, python

Есть необходимость в написании пользовательских скриптов на Python в программе написанной на С++(QT MinGW-32bit).

Вопрос:

Как осуществить их взаимодействия и передачу данных.

Как из программы на C++ так из скриптов на Python.

Приложение на C++ и она занимается отрисовкой GUI и оперирует данными из бд для отображения их в GUI программы. Подразумевается что Python(скрипты) будут реализовывать работу с данными из с++ программы и отдавать их обратно.

Пайплайн бы выглядел примерно так.

(Mysql)->(С++ приложение)<--->(Python сценарий для обработки данных).

Где с++ приложения порождает запуск сценариев на Python.

(Примечание) 
Python не может оперировать напрямую базой данных ,только через с++ приложение.

Comment: В \*nix-ах я бы использовал пару пайпов (или если скрипт реально диалоговый, то псевдотерминал) и соответственно, fork/exec для запуска питона. Наверняка в винде есть аналогичные механизмы.

Comment: [Встраивание питона в приложение](https://docs.python.org/3.7/extending/embedding.html) — тема большай и сложная... в один ответ ИМХО не удастся вместить даже полноценный HelloWorld с полным его описанием, так что предлагаю сразу отправиться читать доки.... или конкретизировать вопрос предоставив **минимальный** вариант «что есть» — «хочу, чтобы питон сделал то-то»

Comment: Всем будет лучше, если пользователь сможет писать скрипты в нормальном редакторе. Взаимодействие можно организовать так же, как и между любыми другими приложениями - через С апи, через сокеты и т.п.

Comment: Проще всего взять библиотеку https://github.com/pybind/pybind11 и встроить интерпретатор как в примере из документации: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/advanced/embedding.html#getting-started

Comment: Предполагается что GUI будет на  c++ а вся бизнес логика на python . Т.к в главу угла ставится легкое модифицирование приложение сторонними людьми.

Comment: Вариант с сокетами отпадает т.к придется писать упаковщик данных это можно сделать быстро и я уже задумывался об этом. Однако проблема в конвертации данных и возможных проблемах с целостностью отталкивают меня.

Comment: С упаковкой данных тоже легко решается: можно взять zmq для передачи данных, а для упаковки выбрать разные готовые варианты в зависимости от объема передаваемых данных json, msgpack, capnp.

Comment: По ссылке, которую дал Fat-Zer, есть даже рабочий пример именно того, что вам нужно - загрузка python-скрипта из C-кода, вызов функции, передача ей списка аргументов и получения результата.

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятно, что вы делаете, можно подумать только о направлениях:

- если вы хотите "прям" консоль python в приложении, то вам придётся добавить в сборку `python` и провести работы по созданию отзывчивого окошка-консоли. У него должна быть с помощью  С++ настроена "среда обработки" должны поступать переменные и пр., ну и возможность из этой среды забирать результаты в С++.
- если вы хотите python-API на свой функционал, то вам придётся писать python-библиотеку обёртку. Пишутся python-сценарий, запускаются и дёргают ваши "либы".
- если вы хотите выполнять python-код в неком `REST` пишите сервисы с песочницей для защиты от инъекций. Посылайте python код и необходимые данные, возвратом забирайте результаты.

Comment: Как я и описывал выше есть приложение на C++ она занимается отрисовкой GUI и оперирует данными из бд для отображения их в GUI программы.
Подразумевается что Python(скрипты) будут реализовывать работу с данными из с++ программы и отдавать их обратно.
Пайплайн бы выглядел примерно так.
(Mysql)->(С++ приложение)<--->(Python сценарий для обработки данных).
Где с++ приложения порождает запуск сценариев на Python.
(Примечание)
Python не может оперировать напрямую базой данных ,только через с++ приложения

Comment: всё равно не понял... python вы где хотите запускать? интерактивно в консоли, в песочнице рядом или на другом сервере? мб вы сможете привести пример аналогичной программы, как jython для веб-сферы, как процедуры на python в БД?

Comment: Скрипты исполняются на локальном компьютере пользователя.
Да думаю самый близкий из вариантов это песочница где этот скрипт будет выполнятся и отдавать результат главной программе.

Comment: можете сделать следующим образом, написать логику и связь приложения со сценариями пользователя на C++ (поставите все заглушки на базу и пр), сделать api на python и позволить ему дёргать пользовательские функции. Т.о. можно будет пользоваться  приложением в командной строке, запуская python-скрипты. Очень удобно и масштабируемо. Python-разработчики оценят.